# Creating tiles for leaflet

Tags: java, leaflet, maptiler

What i want to achieve is user uploading photo through website. 
Then the photo needs to be cut in tiles at backend, and stored in s3.

I want it to be done automatically.

I've implemented a function to crop the photo. Everything is fine with big zoom but when zoom 0 then there is one `256x256` image displayed and it's really bad quality.
Somehow all works fine when I use MapTiler.

Any advice how to do that properly?

Comment: I think you're answering yourself... if "all works fine when I use MapTiler", then... just use MapTiler.

Comment: See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5718/what-methods-are-there-to-produce-map-tiles-for-google-maps ; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5101/how-to-cut-a-tiled-image-from-a-raster-dataset-using-gdal